# Can't ssh tunnel URLs with slashes?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, tunneling

Yes... For example:

```
sh@SH:~$ ssh -L 7777:x10hosting.com:80/free-hosting-signup ______@anapnea.net
```

What I'm doing wrong?

```
Bad local forwarding specification '7777:x10hosting.com:80/free-hosting-signup'
```

How can I tunnel to URLs like those? What is the right way to do it?
A last question: On a website, all links link to the website through http://  etc, not relative links, and that makes me go to the site itself,  without the ssh tunnel. Any way to avoid it? (Except manually typing the URL in the address bar)? Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't tunnel URL's, you're tunneling addresses.

Just do `ssh -L 777:x10hosting.com:80 user@example.com`, and then access `localhost:777/free-hosting-signup` with your browser or script or whatever you're using.

As for your second question, you could set up a dynamic tunnel, like so: `ssh -D 777 user@example.com`, and then set your browser to use a SOCKS5 proxy located at `localhost:777`.

Now your browser makes all the requests via your tunnel.